# Get a variable float value from GUI slider

Tags: python, user-interface, variables, tkinter

Hope you are all doing fine.

I am trying to make a code where I input variable values by using a slider in a GUI. I can get the slider to work and generate the desired values but I can not get to assign the generated value to a variable. I am sure its a simple mistake I am not understanding that probably has to do with the type of value the scale generates but I can't get to fix it.

Here is the code I attempted to do.

```
import math
import sympy
import scipy
from sympy import *
from scipy import optimize
from tkinter import *

def Compute():
    return scaleThetaB.get()

window = Tk()

window.title("Variable Selection")
window.geometry('400x300')
window['bg'] = '#D99D08'

scaleThetaB = Scale(window,from_=0, to=150,length=1000,orient=HORIZONTAL,font=('Arial,20'),tickinterval=10,showvalue=1,resolution=0.1,troughcolor='#990101')
scaleThetaB.pack()
button=Button(window,text='Compute',command=Compute)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()

ThetaB=Compute()
print(ThetaB)
```

Here is a picture of the GUI:
[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbcrP.png)

In this specific case, I would like the assign the value of the slider (79.1) to my variable ThetaB.

And here is the error message:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9APhf.png)

Thank you for trying and helping!

Comment: please post error messages as text and don't use `*` when importing, also remove code after `.mainloop`, in this case it is what causes the error because scale doesn't exist anymore

Comment: oh, and there is no point in using `return` if the command is called by the button, there is no way to access that variable, you may need to use global variables and change their value

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback. The whole point of me trying to use the return was to store the value of the widget in a variable that I need in my code since it is used in equations. How would I do this? Why is it bad to use * when importing?

Comment: Have you tried using a `tkinter.IntVar`, and assigning it to the `variable` argument in the scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign the value to a variable you can simply use global variables and `global`:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Scale, Button

theta_b = 0


def compute():
    global theta_b
    theta_b = scale_theta_b.get()


window = Tk()

window.title("Variable Selection")
window.geometry('400x300')
window['bg'] = '#D99D08'

scale_theta_b = Scale(
    window, from_=0, to=150, length=1000, orient='horizontal',
    font=('Arial', 20), tickinterval=10, showvalue=1, resolution=0.1,
    troughcolor='#990101'
)
scale_theta_b.pack()
button = Button(window, text='Compute', command=compute)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

You don't need to use the global constants such as `HORIZONTAL`, they most of the time represent the same name string just lowercase so I would suggest using those, because you don't need to import anything additionally.

Why not use `*`? Well you import everything, but you may not know or forget all the names that you import, it can cause an issue where from two modules you import the same thing but the last import overrides the first so the name you want to use may not reference the object you think it references. In other words it helps keep the namespace clean.
(additional info: you should either import what you need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that)

Also:
I strongly suggest following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Function and variable names should be in `snake_case`, class names in `CapitalCase`. Don't have space around `=` if it is used as a part of keyword argument (`func(arg='value')`) but have space around `=` if it is used for assigning a value (`variable = 'some value'`). Have space around operators (`+-/` etc.: `value = x + y`(except here `value += x + y`)). Have two blank lines around function and class declarations.

Comment: Perfect exactly what I needed thank you. I will try to get better with my formatting and syntax thanks, much appreciated!